# Round with 0 decimal point

Tags: php, decimal, rounding, zero

My variable is: `$No = '9.80000000000'`
I want a result like this: `$No = '9.80'`

I tried to use the round function with 2 decimal points, but I get results like this: `$No = '9.8'`

I want to have a specific numeric scale precision.
My expected result is: `$No = '9.80'`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`round()` function omits last digit zero so better use the number_format() function.

eg:

```
round($No,2)    //your code.
```

change this function to like below

eg:

```
number_format($No, 2);
```

I hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

the digit 0 has no value after decimal point.
you can use this :

```
echo substr('9.80000000000', 0,4);
```